# Using chrome.browserAction with JQuery for chrome extensions

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know if it is possible to use functions of the kind [chrome.browserAction](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html) with JQuery for Chrome extensions.

Here is the piece of code from my main.js, which should be executed as soon as I click the browser action button. What should I do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){ //line that must be fixed
        //code to be executed           
    });
});
```

Comment: did you try adding code to `//code to be executed?` you should try to do it and see if it works, and then come here to ask questions.

Comment: There's no need for a domready event, because `chrome.browserAction` is always readily available. Is main.js an extension page (background/event page for example)?

Comment: @kennypu Yes I did. The code that usually works fine by itself did not work with the browserAction part.

Comment: @user1576660 show the code then so that we can see.

Comment: @RobW I don't know exactly how to explain this, but I configured the manifest.json so that main.js is executed in the specified matches (any webpage). Again, without the onClicked condition, it works fine on general webpages. (You can see [the extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/m%C3%A1quinas-agr%C3%ADcolas/dgblhpmnnflmignpfajfeiojlgclajbp?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) by yourself. It's pretty random, it replaces every image and video with agricultural machinery)

Comment: @user1576660 That's a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html). Content script have no access to the `chrome.browserAction` API. Use an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages.html) or [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) instead.

Comment: @kennypu Sorry if I am misunderstanding this, but the code is irrelevant. Imagine that it's a simple alert or a console.log("Hello World!");